# JSON Struct to Map[String,String] using sqlContext

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read json data in spark streaming job.
By default `sqlContext.read.json(rdd)` is converting all map types to struct types.

```
|-- legal_name: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- first_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- last_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- middle_name: string (nullable = true)
```

But when i read from hive table using sqlContext

> val a = sqlContext.sql("select * from student_record")

below is the schema.

```
|-- leagalname: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

Is there any way we can read data using `read.json(rdd)` and get Map data type?

Is there any option like 
 `spark.sql.schema.convertStructToMap`?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You need to explicitly define your schema, when calling `read.json`.

You can read about the details in [Programmatically specifying the schema](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#programmatically-specifying-the-schema) in the Spark SQL Documentation.

For example in your specific case it would be

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val schema = StructType(List(StructField("legal_name",MapType(StringType,StringType,true))))
```

That would be one column `legal_name` being a map.

When you have defined you schema you can call
`sqlContext.read.json(rdd, schema)` to create your data frame from your JSON dataset with the desired schema.